# How to replace string of file by output of a command in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm building a project using CMake and I want to replace an expression in a file by the result of the execution of another file. What CMake command can I use ?

I'm preparing the project for using Intel SGX enclave remote attestation. There are three steps :

> 1. Build an executable *mrsigner*
> 2. Extract the enclave SIGSTRUCT and store it in a file *enclave_sigstruct_raw*
> 3. Compute the value MRSIGNER by executing *mrsigner* with *enclave_sigstruct_raw* as argument and store MRSIGNER in the file *policy*

```
## Step 1
add_executable(mrsigner mrsigner.c ${SOURCES})

## Step 2
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw
    COMMAND ${SGX_ENCLAVE_SIGNER} dump -cssfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw -dumpfile /dev/null -enclave ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../bin/enclave.so
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "SIGSTRUCT value extracted ==> ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw")

add_custom_target(sigstruct ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw)

## Step 3
execute_process(
    COMMAND bash "-c" "sed -e \"s^@MRSIGNER@^`${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/mrsigner ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw`^\" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/policy.in > ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/policy"
    DEPENDS mrsigner sigstruct)
```

I managed to obtain the intended results by running two times cmake and make. That's normal because *execute_process* is executed in cmake whereas *add_custom_target* is executed in make. But I want to write a better code that needs only one cmake-make.

I also tried to replace *execute_process* by *add_custom_target* but in this case I got an error with the command execution inside sed `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/mrsigner ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/enclave_sigstruct_raw` :

```
/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/RemoteAttestation/bin/mrsigner /home/ubuntu/RemoteAttestation/app/enclave_sigstruct_raw not found
```

I tried other basic commands like pwd or ls and got not found too. However, if I replace the command by a fixed value like *"sed -e \"s^@MRSIGNER@^123^\"*, the replacement works.

Comment: According to the error message, bash treats `mrsigner` executable plus `enclave_sigstruct_raw` file as a **single argument**. Note, that `execute_process` and `add_custom_target` has slightly different ways for escape characters given in `COMMAND`. You may run `make VERBOSE=1` to see a command line which is executed. Or even examine content of the Makefile generated by CMake. Instead of tricks with escaping, you may write **separate shell script** which performs step 3, and call this script (with parameters) in `add_custom_target`.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, the separate shell script works perfectly !